# Making regex changes to a string holding xml format

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following xml in a string.

```
<field1 param1="value" hun="true">
<field2 hun="true">
<field3 param2="value" hun="true">
```

I want to find every instance of `hun="true">` and add another xml field `<newxml value="number">` So my xml would look like this

```
<field1 param1="value" hun="true">
<newxml value="number">
<field2 hun="true">
<newxml value="number">
<field3 param2="value" hun="true">
<newxml value="number">
```

Comment: BTW, your samples are not well-formed XML (all tags are unclosed)

Comment: `preg_replace('/hun="true">/', 'hun="true">' . "\n" . '<newxml value="number">' . "\n", $xmlData);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could do a simple string replace on the string, replacing every instance of 'hun="true"' with `'hun="true"><newxml value="number">'`

Comment: This would at least distort comments or CDATA sections and definitively destroy attributes if they for some reason contain `hun="true"`.

Answer (score 1):

I dis-recommend regex (or indeed *any* string manipulation tool) for modifying XML. Run your XML through this small XSLT stylesheet instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- this template copies your input XML unchanged... -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ...except for anything with hun="true", where it adds a new element -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@hun = 'true']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <newxml value="number" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The PHP function to use for this task is `xslt_process()` ([see the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xslt-process.php)).

To only add the `<newxml value="number" />` where it is missing, the second template would change to:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[@hun = 'true' 
                         and not(following-sibling::*[1][self::newxml])]
  ">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <newxml value="number" />
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: XSLT is a good solution, but I really think that for this one, the change I want to make is very simple, so it's over kill.

Comment: @park: I gave you a working XSLT stylesheet for your exact problem (as you stated it). How can it get any simpler than that? ;) If you think you must use string-processing on XML, I can't keep you from doing it, though.